# Gtk.Label line wrap not working as expected

Tags: gtk, gtk3, pygobject

when width is sufficient to hold all characters

[image]

when characters exceed width

[image]

i have used set_line_wrap(True).There are two labels in each row as shown in picture, right label in each row has set_line_wrap(True), why is the label in the second row not starting from the beginning? when characters exceeds, i expect it to start from same position where it started before when characters were not exceeding.

Code:

```
 descriptionLabel=Gtk.Label(description)
 descriptionLabel.set_line_wrap(True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `halign` to `Gtk.AlignSTART` and `xalign` to 0. This should ensure that both the label as a whole and each individual line starts at the very left of the available space.

Comment: can you tell me more about what  halign and xalign doing here?

Comment: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkLabel.html#GtkLabel--xalign